# if a word has 5 letters print the word with one letter per line if not then just print the word?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeperateLetters 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word:");
        String w= scan.nextLine();
        for(int i=0; i<w.length();i++)
            System.out.println(w.charAt(i));    
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far and I can't figure how to make it so that if the word is 5 letters or longer to print it one letter per line and if not to just print the word. So far it'll just print any word with one letter per line.

Comment: So you're almost there. Try to use the `if` statement before the `for` `loop` to check if `length()` is `5`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html . And don't forget about the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. The only thing missing is an `if-else` conditional statement, to check whether the word has a length of five. Without this check, you will always print the string one character per line, regardless of its length.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeperateLetters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word:");
        String w = scan.nextLine();
        if (w.length() >= 5) {     // print one char per line if length is 5
            for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++)
                System.out.println(w.charAt(i));
        } else {
            System.out.println(w); // otherwise, print the whole string
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an **if-else** statment to check if `w.length() == 5` or not.

Answer (score 0):

public class SeperateLetters 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word:");
    String w= scan.nextLine();

    if( w.length() > 5) 
    {    
        for(int i=0; i<w.length();i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(w.charAt(i));
        }    
    }
}
```

}